# How do you fight against Geovishap Hatchlings?

Tags: genshin-impact

Since these enemies have spawned in my world, I've had no real idea on how to fight them that would cause them to get into their "stunned" animation, which is them lying on their back for a few seconds while they flail in place.

[image]

So far my strategy has just been to just plug away at them constantly using my carry. Sometimes it'll "stun", sometimes it won't. But I can't/don't necessarily understand the trigger for this. Is it the damage I'm dealing? Am I supposed to attack him during his Sonic the Hedgehog phase?  Or is it something about the geo crystals they spawn while they burrow underground?

How do you fight against Geovishap Hatchlings?

Comment: [Wiki](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Geovishap_Hatchling) say *"when its attacks are deflected by a character with a shield, it seems to be paralyzed for a moment by the recoil"*. Try using geo-skills (perhaps Noelle shield works directly) to generate geo-shield and let monster hit you. I didn't try it yet, avoiding certain monsters is my tactic and those "sonics" are in the avoid-list.

Comment: So I've had a shield up and sometimes it doesnt get stunned, it just chews through all my sheilds and then I get knocked back

Comment: Top tip, they can't swim ;) https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/jc0e20/how_to_kill_geovishap_hatchling/

Comment: Right, but having a body of water close by is no guarantee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intended way (it's even mentioned in advice piece your are receiving after meeting them for the first time): wait for them to drop crystals, collect them to receive a shield buff, tank their attacks while protected by shield.

While trying to record the optimal strategy I figured out they moveset:

Melee attacks:

- regular slashing attacks with one or both arms;
- spinning in place attack.

Ranged attacks:

- rolling around full Sonic that mentioned in this question;
- jumping onto you with traditional red circle on the ground;
- not really an attack - but strategical burrowing with nice side effect of dropping geo crystals. For me this one most often happens right after jumping attack if you run away.

So the best strategy is to stay away from them - they cannot use any melee attacks and are limited to ranged ones. Wait for jumping + burrowing combo and run to collect crystals. Crystals will give you geo type shield and you will be able to tank any of their attacks for some time. This is time to run towards them disregarding what they are doing. If they do sonic rolling attack and run into you - they will get stunned and be laying on the ground for some time.

---

My initial advice about elemental reaction was only partially correct: they are indeed can be stopped (without stunned animation), not by elemental reaction, but by dealing enough damage to them. Could be both melee or ranged attacks.

Comment: Does this method trigger their "stun" animation as I mentioned previously? Where they get knocked onto their backs?

Comment: I will test it this evening and return with results

Comment: @sayu updated answer, still working on recording actual proof

Comment: no need, i tested this out based on your line about the intended way, and it worked perfectly! I think the reason why it worked intermittently for me was because I was trying to tank their cyclone hits while having shield up, whereas the intended way was to tank their charge/rush attack